# core data simple Fetch 

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch

Im using coredata to check the content of an entity, but still remembering how to go about to do it,

```
PFIWIAppDelegate* delegate = (PFIWIAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"productPoints" inManagedObjectContext:[delegate managedObjectContext]]; 

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 

[request setEntity:entity];

NSLog(@" la resposta por deux:: %@", request);


NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[delegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"tu fetch master db ::%@",results);
```

so im sure there are properties in my entity "productPoints" [checked in sqlite Manager)

how to see the data?

in my logs I see

```
la resposta por deux:: <NSFetchRequest: 0x6cd1780> (entity: productPoints; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
2011-12-14 14:50:44.266 PFIWIN0196[7524:fb03] tu fetch master db ::(
"<productPoints: 0x6cd38c0> (entity: productPoints; id: 0x6cd2ce0 <x-coredata://888E340F-6CBF-4EED-B9D9-9C3FB06244F3/productPoints/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
"<productPoints: 0x6cd3b70> (entity: productPoints; id: 0x6cd2cf0 <x-coredata://888E340F-6CBF-4EED-B9D9-9C3FB06244F3/productPoints/p7> ; data: <fault>)"
```

so i guess im seeing the 2 objects of my entity, but how to see the properties,

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objects are in the `results` array, as you surmise.  To see the properties all you have to do is access them, using something along the lines of:

```
productPoints* firstProduct = [results objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog("Some property value:  %@", firstProduct.someProperty);
```

Also note that the standard Core Data API's are absolutely ridiculous for a framework that is supposed to *simplify* the task of storing and retrieving data.  I strongly suggest you try using the `NSManagedObjectContext+EasyFetch` category discussed [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html) and in github [here](https://github.com/halostatue/coredata-easyfetch).

Then your code can be rewritten as:

```
PFIWIAppDelegate* delegate = (PFIWIAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray* results = [[delegate managedObjectContext] fetchObjectsForEntityName: @"productPoints"];
NSLog(@"tu fetch master db ::%@",results);
```

Comment: great aroth! thank you!, for the answer and the >NSManagedObjectContext+EasyFetch